# In reStructuredText, how do you make a table column have monospaced text?

Tags: syntax, markup, restructuredtext

I want to create a table in ReStructuredText (ReST / RST) where every column should be rendered as an [inline literal](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup) / monospace font.

I can't find a way to have inline literals span multiple lines, where there is text in front of them, like a table.

Is there a way for me to set a table to render a specific column as inline literal / monospace font? If not, what is the best practice for this?

Comment: How do you want new lines/carriage returns to appear? What if the inline literal has hundreds of characters, thus blowing out the width of the table?

Comment: I don't know any way to render a column of a table without rendering each line. Would it help you to render a complete table?

Comment: @StevePiercy In my case, the lines are expected to be between 10-30 characters. I'd like to have it all be selected together without selecting new lines / carriage returns.

Comment: @Humbalan I'm using a complete table now, but also trying to keep it within a length of 79 characters, per the [style guide](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html#line-length). But I might give up on line length for tables.

Comment: Was the answer of Steve Piercy sufficient?

Comment: @Humbalan Not quite. It demonstrates the effect I wanted, but my goal was to span monospaced text across multiple rows. It seems to get most of it, but I wanted line breaks to keep my columns around 79 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
.. csv-table::
    :header: Header1, Header2, Header3

    A, B, "These lines appear as one line,
    even though they are written in two lines."
    C, D, "This is normal text. ``this is inline stuff that is very long and may wrap on multiple lines of text in a table cell, and it could look OK, but who knows?`` This is normal text again."
```

Yields this screenshot, using the Alabaster theme.

[image: inline literal in a table cell]

You might have to twiddle your theme's CSS to get it just right.